# get a string property value of a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

in an ios application. I have a UITableView, which contains prototype cells called "MyCustomCell". The "MyCustomCell" contains a button and a NSString property called "cellKey":

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellKey;
@end
```

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath Delegate method, I am assigning the cellKey and adding a tap listener to the button.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    MyItem *item = [self.data objectAtIndex:row];

    NSString *identifier = @"MyCustomCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell =  (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    //Give the cell the key
    cell.cellKey = item.key;
    //add a tap listener
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTaped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}
```

In the buttonTaped handler I want to get the key of the cell corresponding to the button clicked:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTaped:(id)sender
{
    //Get the button
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    //get the super view which is the cell
    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[senderButton superview];
   //get the key
    NSString *key = cell.cellKey;

}
```

However when I run the application and click the button, the app crash when I call cell.cellKey with this error:

```
-[UITableViewCellContentView cellKey]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13576240
```

It is not recognizing that the superView is of type MyCustomCell. So how can I get the "cellKey" property of the cell containing the button clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is actually added to the cell `contentView` so you need to navigate one more level up the `superview` hierarchy to get to the cell.

Comment: THanks, That was the issue